# Finding the minimum of scanner input in a method

Tags: java, methods, minimum

I am trying to find the minimum of a variable input of the scanner class. I have as many inputs as the user wants but I cannot seem to find out how to find the minimum of multiple inputs. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public static void minimum(int count)
{
    double input;
    boolean lessThan;
    double lesser = 0;
    for(count = count; count > 0; count--)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a double: ");
        input = console.nextDouble();
        lessThan = input < input;
        if(lessThan = true)
        {
            lesser = input;
        }
        else
        {
            lesser = input;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The minimum is " + lesser);
}
```

Comment: `if(lessThan = true)` the `x=y` is *assignment* operator which also *returns* assigned value. So `lessThan = true` *assigns* true to `lessThan` variable and also returns `true`. So `if(lessThan = true){..}` is essentially the same as `lessThan = true; if (true){...}`. To *compare* values use `==` operator, or to avoid such mistake skip `== true` and just write `if (lessThan) {...}`.  OR use `if (input < input){...}` directly in `if` condition (BTW do you see the problem with `input < input`? Can it ever be true?)

Comment: Anyway there are a lot of small problem in your code. Like what is the purpose of `count = count` in `for(count = count; count > 0; count--)`? Why in `else` you are doing same thing as in case where condition is true?

Comment: the purpose for count = count is to set count equal to itself so that i get the correct int for how many doubles the user requires the program to process. I cannot figure out how to compare input with the later values of input and store it in a variable.

Comment: "to set count equal to itself" lets say `count` holds some value like 4. What we execute `count = count` will something change? No, it will still hold `4`. Coding is about applying some *changes*, if nothing happens such code is not needed. You can skip `count = count` and write `for ( ; count>0; count--){ .. }` or use good old `while (count > 0) { .. ; count--}`.

Comment: okay I will fix that, do you have any advice on comparing input with itself considering that input = console.nextDouble(); has multiple values?

Comment: It will have *one value at a time* (one value per iteration). It is like searching max value in list of numbers, for instance 4,2,3,5,1. First you assign as `max` first number, so 4. Then you read next number which is 1. You compare that `current` value with `max` and if it is greater you assign that value to max, if not then you do nothing and move to another value. And so on until you read all numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer but my answer is a little bit different. Firstly I created an initialized array because we need to execute the code several times, then I stored the user inputs into the array after that I found the min value using array indexes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        double arr[] = new double[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the double");
            arr[i] = scanner.nextDouble();
        }
        double min = arr[0];
        for (int j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
            if(arr[j]<min)
                min=arr[j];
        }
        System.out.println("min value is"+" "+min);
    }
```

Comment: I do not think I am allowed to use arrays for this project. Your code has helped me on the logic side. Is there a way to reference a certain number just out of the scanner?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("How many inputs?: ");
    int answer = scanner.nextInt();
    int arr[] = new int[answer];
    int y = 0;
    
    while(y < answer){
        System.out.println("Enter a value: ");
        arr[y] = scanner.nextInt();
        
        y++;
    }
    int smallNum = arr[arr.length - 1];
    for(int i = arr.length; i > 0; i--){
        if(smallNum > arr[i - 1]){
            smallNum = arr[i - 1];
        }
    }
     System.out.println("Minimum is: " + smallNum);
}
```

Comment: Another way, which is assuming that the last number of the array is the smallest, and then we use that number to compare or traverse through the array looking for other smaller numbers.